# Failed to fetch forge manifest - autodesk forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I was working with a forge viewer for past few weeks.It was fine and I've developed 2 extensions for it and now the application has been shaped well.It's been a while I've looked at the viewer and all of a sudden I'm unable to work with the viewer.The same code working before was not working now.

I can see some changes in documentation stuffs of autodesk forge viewer.Is there any breaking changes.I've been following previous documentation of model-derivative api for preparing file for the viewer.

If I try to run the viewer,I'm getting this error.

`Failed fetching Forge manifest`

I'll attach a screenshot of the networks tab result,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lG7VA.png

Similarly when I try to run fetch using postman with this end point,

```
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/:urn/manifest
```

I'm getting,

```
  {
    "developerMessage": "Token scope not set. This request does not have the required privilege.",
    "moreInfo": "https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/developers_guide/error_handling/",
    "errorCode": "AUTH-010"
}
```

But this was working before.For this endpoint, setting scope is optional as per the documentation.I've tried the same before, it worked.

I'll leave the documentation for your reference

https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-GET/

What am I doing wrong?Anything essential I've missed or any breaking changes.I was confused because I'm getting the same response even with a basic viewer code(simplifying all my extra extension logics).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per our [documentation](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-GET/#resource-information) it is the `user context` that is optional and not `oauth scopes` - the following scopes have always been required to access the manifest:

```
Required OAuth Scopes   
data:readorviewables:read
```

If you could access this endpoint with no scopes specified then it was an oversight on our part and must have been fixed now ...